# Android Unit Test: ActivityMonitor waitForActivityWithTimeout return NULL, getActivity never returns, INJECT_EVENTS permission error

Tags: android, unit-testing

I'm using Android testing framework as recommended by Google: ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2. I have been suffering the following errors at **RANDOM** test runs, but with persistent fatality. It means sometimes all tests passed (happy!), but many times it failed randomly with either one of these three errors. It is frustrating, and make me have no confidence in the test results.

To describe the issues in detail, I provided my test class' simplified pseudo code and the three issues below. Both test cases are **independent** of each other.

```
public class FirstActivityTest 
extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FirstActivity> {
    private FirstActivity mActivity;
    private ActivityMonitor mActivityMonitor;

    public FirstActivityTest () {
        super(FirstActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);

        mActivity = getActivity();
        assertNotNull("Cannot start test since target Activity is NULL!", mActivity);

        mActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(SecondActivity.class.getName(), null, false);
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        if(mActivity != null) {
            mActivity.finish();
            mActivity = null;
        }
        if(mActivityMonitor != null) {
            getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(mActivityMonitor);
            mActivityMonitor = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open FirstActivity, enter a text and click submit button. 
     * Verifies SecondActivity is open.
     */
    public void testA_HappyPath() {
        Activity secondActivity = null;
        try {
            //(Omitted) Get edit text and enter a valid value
            //(Omitted) Find submitButton view
            //Click submit button
            TouchUtils.clickView(this, submitButton);

            //Wait for result and validate:
            secondActivity = mActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(10000);
            assertNotNull("Result SecondActivity should NOT be null!", secondActivity );
        } finally {
            //Clean up:
            if(secondActivity != null) {
                secondActivity .finish();
                secondActivity = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open FirstActivity, do NOT enter a text and click submit button. 
     * Verifies error message is returned.
     */
    public void testB_SadPath() {
        //(Omitted) Find submitButton view
        //Click submit button
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, submitButton);

        //(Omitted) Validate error message is displayed
    }
}
```

Now, I ran these two test cases over and over (they will run in alphabetical order), the following results:

1. Both test cases passed, OR
2. testA_HappyPath() failed because the ActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout() returned NULL SecondActivity. But when I looked at my device, SecondActivity is displayed correctly. Somehow, the test failed to notice it. Why?
3. When testA_HappyPath() failed, then the next testB_SadPath() would hang during setUp() > getActivity() indefinitely. I think I shut down everything in the tearDown(). Why?
4. testB_SadPath() often failed on TouchUtils.clickView() with the following error: "Injecting to another application requires **INJECT_EVENTS permission**" (regardless if testA_HappyPath passes or fails). Why?

Any helpful feedbacks is appreciated. Thanks!

---

I have dealt with these 3 issues for few days by now, studied many suggestions all over the internet and did several try-and-error. Not a single one solved particular problem right away, however - by combining what I found I solved the issue (1) and (2) above, but still have issue (3) un-resolved. Below is the detail what fix I did to make this work.

ISSUE (1) ActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout() returned NULL

1.1. I learned now that I must declare getInstrumentation().addMonitor() BEFORE the getActivit(). Please see how I changed the setUp() method and this somehow fixed the issue. Anyone who understands why this is requirement please let us know, we appreciate it.

1.2. On emulator, this call could occasionally returned NULL causing test to fail. I learned it is because the waiting time was too low. Thus, increase the waiting time helps to prevent ActivityMonitor to return too early.

ISSUE (2) The next testB_SadPath() would hang during setUp() > getActivity() indefinitely

2.1. As I described above, this occurred when the previous test (testA_HappyPath) failed. I thought my tearDown() cleaned everything and have the next test ready to run. What happened is that, testA was waiting for SecondActivity to show up on the screen but since ActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout() returned NULL, testA failed. The tearDown() was executed just fine. The problem is that SecondActivity indeed showed up on screen, but it never gets shutdown in the finally block because its method instance 'secondActivity' was still null. Having SecondActivity alive and lingers on the screen caused the next getActivity() to hang. I fixed this by changing the finally block to make sure if SecondActivity ever exists, it gets shutdown.

These changes are summarized in the code below (See the setUp() and finally block).

```
public class FirstActivityTest 
extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<FirstActivity> {
    private FirstActivity mActivity;
    private ActivityMonitor mActivityMonitor;

    public FirstActivityTest () {
        super(FirstActivity.class);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        if(mActivity != null) {
            mActivity.finish();
            mActivity = null;
        }
        if(mActivityMonitor != null) {
            getInstrumentation().removeMonitor(mActivityMonitor);
            mActivityMonitor = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open FirstActivity, enter a text and click submit button. 
     * Verifies SecondActivity is open.
     */
    public void testA_HappyPath() {
        mActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(SecondActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

        mActivity = getActivity();
        assertNotNull("Cannot start test since target Activity is NULL!", mActivity);

        Activity secondActivity = null;
        try {
            //(Omitted) Get edit text and enter a valid value
            //(Omitted) Find submitButton view
            //Click submit button
            TouchUtils.clickView(this, submitButton);

            //Wait for result and validate:
            secondActivity = mActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(20000);
            assertNotNull("Result SecondActivity should NOT be null!", secondActivity );
        } finally {
            //Clean up:
            if(secondActivity == null) {
                //If empty, wait longer because need to shut down the foreground activity, if any: 
                secondActivity = mActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(20000);
            }
            if(secondActivity != null) {
                secondActivity .finish();
                secondActivity = null;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Open FirstActivity, do NOT enter a text and click submit button. 
     * Verifies error message is returned.
     */
    public void testB_SadPath() {
        mActivity = getActivity();
        assertNotNull("Cannot start test since target Activity is NULL!", mActivity);

        //(Omitted) Find submitButton view
        //Click submit button
        TouchUtils.clickView(this, submitButton);

        //(Omitted) Validate error message is displayed
    }
}
```

ISSUE (3) testB_SadPath() often failed on TouchUtils.clickView() with the following error: "Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"

I still cannot resolve this last issue :-(

Comment: When I had this error about INJECT_EVENTS it was because I was trying to press a button that was hiding underneath the soft keyboard. I am using the android espresso library for testing and they have a utility method to close the soft keyboard which solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

ISSUE (3) testB_SadPath() often failed on TouchUtils.clickView() with the following error: "Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"

I found an alternative way to avoid this issue on my Android Unit Test. Instead of using TouchUtils.clickView(), I perform directly a click operation on the button itself by invoking the performClick(). The following modified test code solves my occasional INJECT_EVENTS permission error. In particular, see the populateDataAndClickSubmit().

```
/**
 * Open FirstActivity, enter a text and click submit button. 
 * Verifies SecondActivity is open.
 */
public void testA_HappyPath() {
    mActivityMonitor = getInstrumentation().addMonitor(SecondActivity.class.getName(), null, false);

    mActivity = getActivity();
    assertNotNull("Cannot start test since target Activity is NULL!", mActivity);

    Activity secondActivity = null;
    try {
        String dataValue = "MyNameIsNoLongerFooNorBar";
        populateDataAndClickSubmit(dataValue);

        //Wait for result and validate:
        secondActivity = mActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(20000);
        assertNotNull("Result SecondActivity should NOT be null!", secondActivity );
    } finally {
        //Clean up:
        if(secondActivity == null) {
            //If empty, wait longer because need to shut down the foreground activity, if any: 
            secondActivity = mActivityMonitor.waitForActivityWithTimeout(20000);
        }
        if(secondActivity != null) {
            secondActivity.finish();
            secondActivity = null;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Open FirstActivity, do NOT enter a text and click submit button. 
 * Verifies error message is returned.
 */
public void testB_SadPath() {
    mActivity = getActivity();
    assertNotNull("Cannot start test since target Activity is NULL!", mActivity);

    String dataValue = null;
    populateDataAndClickSubmit(dataValue);

    //(Omitted) Validate error message is displayed
}

private void populateDataAndClickSubmit(final String dataValueString) {
    final EditText editDataView = //(omitted) find it from the activity layout
    final Button submitButton = //(Omitted) Find submitButton view

    mActivity.runOnUiThread(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    editDataView.setText(dataValueString);
                    submitButton.performClick();
               }
            }
        );

    //Wait and allow app to be idle while performClick to finish and activity re-drawn:
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
}
```

**NOTES:**

1. This solution is not an answer to why touchUtils.clickView() throws occasional inject event permission error
2. The View.performClick() requires your activity to have the View in question implement OnClickListener(). In my case, the SubmitButton already has so it is a convenience test code change.
3. The getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync() allows for the test code to idle until the app finish the work and re-draw its layout appropriately. This same line is performed within touchUtils.clickView() if you look at its java code.